# Why is the program print 0 for the number of even elements in the array , I have used faster approach using the bitwise operators?

Tags: arrays, c, bitwise-operators

// here I have tried to print the number of positive , negative ,even , odd , elements in the array . The rest of the output is right , except it is print 0 in case of even , when obviously they are not 0.So What is the bug here!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{ 

    int arr[10] = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 13, 15, -2, -4};
    int pos = 0;
    int neg = 0;
    int even = 0;
    int odd = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] & 1 == 0)
        {
            even++;
        }
        if (arr[i] & 1 == 1)
        {
            odd++;
        }
        if (arr[i] > 0)
        {
            pos++;
        }
        else if (arr[i] < 0)
        {
            neg++;
        }
    }
    printf("the odd are %d ,the even are %d ,the positive are %d , the negative are %d\n", odd, even, pos, neg);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging it? Pick a language please. I would suggest enabling warnings `-Wall`, compiler will warn you about your bug.

Answer (score 4):

This is because of [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

`arr[i] & 1 == 0` is equivalent to `arr[i] & (1 == 0)`, which is `arr[i] & 0`, which is obviously 0, so the condition is always false.

You want to do this instead:

```
if ((arr[i] & 1) == 0)
{
    even++;
}
if ((arr[i] & 1) == 1)
{
    odd++;
}
```

The odd test already works because `arr[i] & 1 == 1` is `arr[i] & (1 == 1)` which is `arr[i] & 1` which is equivalent to what you were checking anyway.

Comment: Meta answer: Never rely on knowledge of operator precedence, either yours or that other person reading your code. *Always* put parenthesis in compund statements to make precedence explicit.

Comment: thanks I'll keep that in mind

Comment: @DevSolar This is definitely good practice for the non-mathematical operators like this (especially when mixing different kinds of operators). Many compilers even give warnings recommending parentheses in cases like this depending on the warning levels. For mathematical operators I think you can mostly avoid them, e.g. `a = x * y + z;` rather than `a = (x * y) + z;` since most programmers should know PEMDAS/BODMAS/etc

Comment: Well yes, they *should*. But I've seen careless refactorings resulting in issues in that regard as well. And rules of thumb are remembered better the shorter they are. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`arr[i] & 1 == 0` is always zero because of operator precendence.
It is equivalent with `arr[i] & (1 == 0)` which is clearly not what you want.

Try

```
if ((arr[i] & 1) == 0) {
    even++
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`&` has lower precedence than `==`, so `arr[i] & 1 == 0` is structure as `arr[i] & (1 == 0)` instead of `(arr[i] & 1) == 0`. To get the latter, you must use explicit parentheses.

Turn on warnings in your compiler, elevate them to errors, and pay attention to the compiler messages. With Clang, start with `-Wmost -Werror`. With GCC, start with `-Wall -Werror`. With MSVC, start with `/W3 /WX`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is the conditions you're using. They're wrong.
The correct way to find out whether a number is odd or even is this:

```
if (num % 2 == 0)
{
    // Even
}
if (num % 2 != 0)
{
    // Odd
}
```

So the final code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int arr[10] = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 13, 15, -2, -4 };
    int pos = 0;
    int neg = 0;
    int even = 0;
    int odd = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            even++;
        }
        if (arr[i] % 2 != 0)
        {
            odd++;
        }
        if (arr[i] > 0)
        {
            pos++;
        }
        else if (arr[i] < 0)
        {
            neg++;
        }
    }
    printf("the odd are %d ,the even are %d ,the positive are %d , the negative are %d\n", odd, even, pos, neg);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: They are not wrong `a & 1` and `a % 2` is pretty much equal for binary representation of numbers. Problem is in operator precedence.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too. Thanks for informing me. I never used the OP's way of finding odd/even numbers.

Comment: @Slava: For testing even/odd, `a % 2 == 0` is correct. `a & 1` fails for one’s complement representations. Since the C standard allows one’s complement, `a & 1` is wrong for maximally portable code.